# How to detect operation system during installation then install compatible file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, installation, windows-installer

I have a Visual Studio C++ MSI package that is compatible with Windows XP, and I have another one that is compatible with Windows Vista, 7, 8.

So, I have two MSI files. Now, what I want is, the application merge both MSI files into one exe file and during installation the application detects the Operating System and select that compatible MSI for installation. XP should install XP MSI and Win7 should install Win7 MSI.

Is there any application that provide this kind of functionality ? How can I do that ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two MSI into one package, you could use either Bootstrapped EXE or Chained MSI. 
Chained MSI: 
You add 2 MSI into new one MSI. And use property `VersionNT` in conditions for choosing needed. 
Condition for Windows XP will be `VersionNT<600`, for Windows Vista and above `VersionNT>600`.
Bootstrapped: 
You add 2 MSI into one Setup.exe.
Try http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/. It's free and simple to use. Or read information about [Windows Installer Bootstrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Chained MSI seems easy and nice. I understand what you are saying but how to add two MSI into one ? Can I do inside the Visual Stdio ? and where to put conditions ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't familiar with VS. One thing I could refer you it's documentation [Multiple-Package Installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736322(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN. There is information regarding needed tables. Conditions should be set in table `MsiEmbeddedChainer` with MSIs.
But perhaps there is some easier way in VS, instead of pure creating .

Comment: I think it will take so much time to learn it. anyways, I am moving to dotnetinstaller, let me try to use it. :)